# How to change permissions depend on different instance using Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django rest framework, and my model is like this, Every Act can have more than one post.

```
class Act(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("common.MyUser", related_name="act_user")
    act_title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    act_content = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    act_type = models.IntField()
   

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("common.MyUser", related_name="post_user")
    act = models.ForeignKey("activities.Act", related_name="post_act")
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    post_content = models.CharField(max_length=140)
```

my view.py in DRF:

```
class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostAllSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer): #self is a instance of class or is a class here?
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

This works fine, but what I want now is if act_type = 1 means this is a private Act and only the act author can create post under this act.I wonder how to use different permission_classes depend on different Act.Maybe looks like:

```
class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    if self.act_type == 1:
        permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,IsActCreatorOrReadOnly)
    else
        permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostAllSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer): #self is a instance of class or is a class here?
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

And I also want to know how to write this permissions.py:

```
class IsActCreatorOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to only allow owners of an object to edit it.
    """
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        return obj.act.user == request.user
```

I don't know what obj really means here, and the error tell me obj.act doesn't exist.

### EDIT

Here is my postSerializer.

```
class PostAllSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Posts api fields"""
    post_user = UserSerializer(source="user", read_only=True)
    post_author = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.user_name')
    
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ("id", "act", "post_author", "post_title", "post_content",)
```

I tried this, but not working, I still can create the post even I'm not the author of the Act(but the act_id is wrong):

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    act_type = request.data.get("act_type") 
    if act_type == 0:
        act_id = request.data.get("act")
        act = Act.objects.get(pk=act_id)
        if request.user != act.user:
            return Response(status=403)
    return super().create(request)
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your `PostSerializer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using different permission classes, there is the `get_permissions` method that you can overwrite on your `PostList` view:

```
def get_permissions(self):
    if self.request.method == 'POST':
        return (OnePermission(),)
    elif  # other condition if you have:
        return (AnotherPermission(),)
    return (YetAnotherPermission(),)
```

However, in your case you can't use object level permissions, because you don't have an object instance yet. From the DRF [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#object-level-permissions) (highlights by me):

> REST framework permissions also support object-level permissioning. Object level permissions are used to determine if a user should be allowed **to act on a particular object,** which will typically be a model instance.
>   Object level permissions are run by REST framework's generic views when .get_object() is called.

When doing a `POST` request, you don't have any object yet, thus the object level permissions won't be invoked.

One way you could achieve what you want is by checking it in the `create` method of `PostList` view. Something like this (hypothetical code):

```
class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    ...

    def create(self, request):
        act_id = request.data.get('act')  # depending on your PostSerializer, the logic of getting act id can vary a little
        act = Act.objects.get(pk=act_id)  # assuming act always exists, otherwise account for in-existing act
        if act.user != request.user:
            return Response({details: "You shall not pass!!!", status=200)  # change to a status and message you need here

        # logic of Post creation here
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you iulian, I'd edit my post, still not working.

Comment: What exactly did you edit? Has anything changed? Where the problem occurs?

Comment: I add PostSerializer.py and add the "create" method which I didn't override before.

Comment: is your `common.MyUser` class the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` of the project or do you have a standard user model with a relationship to `MyUser`?